# configuring package.json on windows

Tags: reactjs, npm, package.json, yarnpkg, npm-scripts

I'm trying to manage the configuration of a react project on windows, it was previously running on mac. I'm using `yarn build`. inside the `package.json` `scripts>build` was configured as `"rm-rf deployment/static;react-scripts build && mv build deployment/static"`. since the `rm-rf` and `mv` commands are for Linux, I tried using `rmdir/del` and `move` instead.. but it doesn't seem to work. I'm getting the error: `Parameter format not correct - "static"`.

Comment: Are you looking for a Windows only equivalent? Or a solution which ensures your `build` script runs successfully across platforms (i.e. Windows/Linux/Mac) ?

Comment: @RobC it works fine on mac. I'm looking for a solution for Windows.

Answer (score 9):

### Windows Solution (cmd.exe)

The equivalent of that `build` script running via *Command Prompt* or *PowerShell* on Windows is:

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "rd /s/q \"deployment/static\" 2> nul & react-scripts build && md \"deployment/static\" && move \"build\" \"deployment/static\""
}
```

**Explanation:**

1. The `rm-rf` equivalent for Windows (cmd.exe) is [`rd /s/q`](https://ss64.com/nt/rd.html)
2. The `mv` equivalent for Windows (cmd.exe) is [`move`](https://ss64.com/nt/move.html)
3. All directory paths have been wrapped in escaped double quotes `\"...\"`. For example;

   `deployment/static` has been rewritten as `\"deployment/static\"`.

   Although escaped double quotes are not entirely necessary in this scenario, it's good practice and necessary to do this when paths may include spaces or punctuation characters.
4. The semi-colon `;` has been replaced with the single `&` operator to ensure the `react-script build` part runs regardless of whether the initial `rd /s/q ...` command fails or succeeds.
5. The following error message would be printed to the console when using `rd` to delete a folder/path which may not exist:

   > The system cannot find the path specified

   To prevent this error message from potentially being printed to the console we redirect the error message to `NUL` using the [`2> nul`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/110930/redirecting-error-messages-from-command-prompt-stderr-stdout) part.
6. The `md \"deployment/static\"` part utilizes Windows [`md`](https://ss64.com/nt/md.html) command to make the `static` directory - which is very similar to the `mkdir` command in bash.

**Note:** The above syntax will fail on *nix* based operating systems such as macOS and Linux.

---

### Cross Platform Solution (Windows/Linux/macOS...)

To achieve a cross platform solution, (i.e. one which runs successfully on Windows, Linux, and macOS), I suggest writing two Nodejs utility scripts to substitute the [`rm -rf`](https://ss64.com/bash/rm.html) and [`mv`](https://ss64.com/bash/mv.html) bash commands. These two Nodejs scripts can then be invoked via your npm-script.

The following steps describe how this can be achieved.

1. Install [shelljs](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs) which provides portable Unix shell commands for Nodejs. To do this, `cd` to your project directory an run the following command:

   ```
   npm i -D shelljs
   ```
2. Create a new Nodejs script named `rm.js` with the following content:

   **rm.js**

   ```js
   const shell = require('shelljs');

   const args = process.argv.slice(2);
   const dir = args[0];

   shell.rm('-rf', dir);
   ```

   Save this file in the root of your project directory, at the same level as where your projects `package.json` is stored.
3. Create a another Nodejs script named `mv.js` with the following content:

   **mv.js**

   ```js
   const shell = require('shelljs');

   const args = process.argv.slice(2);
   const src = args[0];
   const dest = args[1];

   // Check src path has been provided and is valid
   if (!src || !shell.test('-d', src)) {
     console.log('\x1b[31m\x1b[40mERR!\x1b[0m src path cannot be found: %s', src);
     process.exit(1);
   }

   // Check dest path has been provided.
   if (!dest) {
     console.log('\x1b[31m\x1b[40mERR!\x1b[0m dest path must be provided:');
     process.exit(1);
   }

   // Make dest directory if necessary.
   shell.mkdir('-p', dest);

   // Move the file.
   shell.mv(src, dest);
   ```

   Also save this file in the root of your project directory, at the same level as where your projects `package.json` is stored.
4. Then configure your `build` script in `package.json` as follows:

   ```json
   "scripts": {
     "build": "node rm \"deployment/static\" & react-scripts build && node mv \"build\" \"deployment/static\""
   }
   ```

**Note**

The two utility scripts `rm.js` and `mv.js` are invoked in the `npm-script` named `build` via the parts reading; `node rm ...` and `node mv ...` respectively.

If you decide to store these two scripts in a different folder instead of the projects root directory, (as suggested in steps 2 and 3 previously), then you'll need to change the paths to the files. For example; if they were both saved in a folder named `scripts` which is located in the root of your project directory then your `build` script would be changed to:

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "node scripts/rm \"deployment/static\" & react-scripts build && node scripts/mv \"build\" \"deployment/static\""
}
```

---

#### Edit / Update:

An alternative cross-platform solution, (which wasn't available when originally posting this answer), is to utilize the [shx](https://github.com/shelljs/shx) package, which is described as:

> `shx` is a wrapper around [ShellJS](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs) Unix commands, providing an easy solution for simple Unix-like, cross-platform commands in npm package scripts

1. Run the following command to install `shx`:

   ```
   npm i -D shx
   ```
2. Then change your build script in `package.json` as follows:

   ```json
   "scripts": {
     "build": "shx rm -rf deployment/static & react-scripts build && shx mv build deployment/static"
   }
   ```

---

Comment: It worked with rmdir after the static folder being manually deleted and created in the project. sorry for late response.

Comment: No worries @izengod - In Windows `rmdir /s/q` and `rd /s/q` are [equivalent](https://www.computerhope.com/rmdirhlp.htm#syntax), so it should work with either. The `/s` argument is necessary when the folder is not empty.

Comment: Good answer. The step md \"deployment/static\" is probably not needed for the Windows environment as it copies the build folder under static folder rather than just copying the static folder.

Answer (score 2):

I use [rimraf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf) for this very reason. 
Install it globally

```
    npm i -g rimraf
```

and update your script as follows

```
    "rimraf deployment/static;react-scripts build && mv build deployment/static"
```

Comment: $ rimraf deployment/static;react-scripts build && move build deployment/static
The system cannot find the file specified.
error Command failed with exit code 1.

Answer (score 1):

The [shx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shx) package should work very well; they even show `rm -rf` in the topmost package.json demo

Some of my coworkers use [rimraf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf) which is specifically the `rm -rf` unix command for node

Answer (score 0):

for Windows:

in client folder

```
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build-win": "react-scripts build && move build ..\\server\\public",
  },
```

that will move folder to **server** folder